# Получение списка пользователей

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

Прошу помочь... Необходимо получить список пользователей. Использую функцию:

```
void FindUser() {
    comboBox1->Items->Clear();
    LPUSER_INFO_3 ui = NULL;
    (LPBYTE*) ui = NULL; // ОШИБКА error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value
    DWORD dwRead = 0;
    DWORD dwTotal = 0;

    NetUserEnum(NULL, 3, FILTER_NORMAL_ACCOUNT,
                (LPBYTE * ) & ui, (DWORD) - 1, &dwRead,
                &dwTotal, NULL);

    for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwRead; i++) {
        comboBox1->Items->Add(Convert::ToString(ui->usri3_name));
        ui++;
    }
}
```

Получаю ошибку

> fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals...

Как правильно сделать? Как исправить? Прошу, помогите!

Comment: Так про какую именно ошибку ваш вопрос? "left operand must be l-value" или "unresolved externals"?

Comment: Могу предположить что не хватает заголовка `#include <lm.h>`, а строка `(LPBYTE *)ui = NULL;` просто лишняя, надо убрать. И функция живёт в Netapi32.dll

Comment: @NewView, спасибо! Действительно забыла про dll... Вы не знаете, почему Convert::ToString(ui->usri3_name) возвращает TRUE, а не имя пользователя?

Comment: Метод `Convert::ToString` ожидает на входе тип из _управляемого_ кода .NET. Вы ему подсовываете _нативный_ тип. Поэтому выбирается перегрузка с входным параметром `bool`.